# Cauchy sequence of Functions

Tags: cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function

> Formally, given a metric space $(X, d)$, a 
>   $x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$ is Cauchy, if for every 
>   positive real number $ε > 0$ there is a 
>   positive integer $N$ such that for all 
>   positive integers $m, n > N$, the 
>   distance, $d(x_m, x_n) < ε$.

- suppose $f_n:(X,d_x)→(Y,d_y)$ for all $n$.
- If a sequence of functions is a cauchy sequence in $(Y,d_y)$, what does this  mean? Does the positive number $N$ depends on $x$?

Comment: In order that a sequence of things is a Cauchy sequence, there must be a distance on the space to which those things belong to. So, you should start by stating which distance you are taking in the space of all functions from $X$ to $Y$. Or, if it's not the set of all functions but only some of them, you should state which functions you'r taking.

Comment: The sequence of functions is cauchy in C(X→Y), the space of bounded and continuous functions from X→Y. Whta if the metrics of X and Y are not specific (say dx and dy), what is the definition of cauchy sequence of functions in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are working in the space of bounded and continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ and that the distance in that space is$$d(f,g)=\sup\left\{d_Y\bigl(f(x),g(x)\bigr)\,\middle|\,x\in X\right\},$$then a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists p\in\mathbb{N})(\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N})(\forall x\in X):d_Y\bigl(f_m(x),f_n(x)\bigr)<\varepsilon.$$